# how to pass directly variable name as dict key with json.loads in python?

Tags: python, json, load

I'm making a script that write other script, arguments are passed as JSON while calling the script from terminal.

The script that need to be written contains a dictionnary.
One of the key value in this dict is a variable name (not a string) call strategy.

My problem looks like this.

```
d = json.loads(sys.argv[2])

# d should looks like that
d = {
  "stopLossValue": 5,
  "strategy": strategy,
  "strategyTitle": "week5"
}

dic = """
parameterDict = {}
""".format(json.dumps(d, sort_keys=True, indent=4))
```

Running the script return an error that disapear if i set strategy key value as string.

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "updateCandleStrategy.py", line 11, in <module>
    d = json.loads(sys.argv[2])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/json/__init__.py", line 318, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/json/decoder.py", line 343, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/json/decoder.py", line 361, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError(errmsg("Expecting value", s, err.value)) from None
ValueError: Expecting value: line 1 column 506 (char 505)
```

Is there a simple way to achieve my goal?

Thanks

Comment: How do you expect to pass a JSON _string_ containing a variable via cmd line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when passing a `json` string from command line, there's a great chance that one of the quotes / escape char is interpreted by the underlying shell.

So that's not a viable/reliable method to pass `json` strings. Pass a file containing json data instead and read it:

```
with open(sys.argv[2]) as f:
   d = json.load(f)
```

Example from windows console, just printing second argument:

```
S:\python>foo.py ff "d = {"s":12,"d":15}"
d = {s:12,d:15}
```

the quotes have been removed. Would need to double them.

On a Linux terminal, wrapping your argument into single quotes could solve most situations, though, until you stumble on a value containing a single quote...

Instead of passing a dictionary, why not using `getopt` or `argparse` and build/parse a proper command line?

Comment: thanks, will try.  I've found a turn around so far by doing string manipulation and replacing "strategy", with strategy but I thought something else may be more elegant

Comment: see my edit, a standard command line parsing could be OK for a relatively small number of data.